# Showing that $\sqrt[105]{105}>\sqrt[106]{106}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, number-comparison

How can one prove that

$$\sqrt[105]{105}>\sqrt[106]{106}\text{ ?}$$
Induction on the statement $$\sqrt[n]{n}>\sqrt[n+1]{n+1} \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}| n>2$$ would yield $\sqrt[3]{3}>\sqrt[4]{4}$ at the base step $n=3$, which we cannot assume.

So, based on the properties of powers and square roots alone, can we prove the first statement?

EDIT: No calculus, no functions, not even logs.

It's more of a riddle that anything else.

Comment: Hint: study $f(x)=e^{\frac{log x}{x}}$.

Comment: How about this for the base case: $81>64$ and the real-12th-root function is strictly increasing.

Comment: In generally, we think some special function so I recommend $f(x)=x^{1/x}$

Comment: Are you saying it's a riddle in that you know the particular solution that you have in mind?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I do not know the solution yet, but there must be one.

Comment: Hm… I know how to do it, but only if you can prove that $n^x>x+1$ for all $x>0$ where $n\ge 3$, $n\in N$. (Or, specifically, for $n=105$)

Comment: @columbus8myhw you can do that with binomial expansion, or Taylor series for non-integer powers

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Posted my answer.

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this is to simply note that the function $x^{1/x}$ is decreasing over a range including $105$ and $106$.

To this end, it suffices to show that $\ln[x^{1/x}] = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ is decreasing over such a range.

We calculate:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \right) = 
\frac{1 - \ln(x)}{x^2}
$$
So, this function is decreasing when $1 - \ln(x) < 0 \implies x > e$.  So, the function is decreasing over the range $(e,\infty)$, which suffices for our purposes.

---

For that base step, should you want to prove this without calculus:
$$
3^{1/3} > 4^{1/4} \iff\\
3^4 > 4^3 \iff \\
81 > 64 \quad \checkmark
$$

Comment: That is true, but can it be shown using only properties of powers and roots alone?

Comment: This is using the properties of powers and roots alone... the differential properties.  Do you mean that you're looking for a calculus-free proof?

Comment: Indeed, I should have clarified

Answer (score 6):

This is equivalent to:
$$105^{1/105}>1+\frac1{105}$$
(which apparently can be proven using binomial expansions).

Proof:
\begin{align}
105^{1/105}&>1+\frac1{105}\\
105^{1/105}&>\frac{106}{105}\\
105^{1+1/105}&>106\\
105^{106/105}&>106\\
105^{1/105}&>106^{1/106}
\end{align}

Comment: Or, equivalent to $105>\left(1+\frac{1}{105}\right)^{105}$. That makes the relationship to the binomial theorem a little more obvious.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How would you even prove that, anyway? The only thing I can think of is $(1+\frac1{105})^{105}\approx e<105$, but that's not rigorous (and also it kinda appeals to calc).

Comment: See my answer for a proof using the binomial expansion.

Comment: Binomial Theorem with fraction exponents, to me, is even scarier than Calculus. But if that's what OP wants, it may work. Besides, with the presence of negative terms, it's not clear why the inequality is obvious.

Comment: @QuangHoang See Andrews' comment; you don't need fractional exponents. TonyK wrote out a proof of the first expression.

Comment: I know. I was trying to say that you left out the most essential (and difficult) part of the proof: It's not "apparently".

Answer (score 6):

This generalizes to $n^{n+1}>(n+1)^n$ or, by the binomial theorem,
$$n.n^n>n^n+{n\choose1}n^{n-1}+{n\choose2}n^{n-2}+\cdots+{n\choose {n-1}}n+1.$$
*Noting that the first two terms are exactly $n^n$*, it remains to show that each term, *starting from the 3rd -- Thanks @TonyK*, on the RHS is less than $n^n$, which is clear for $n$ large (Hint: What is $n\choose k$?).

One may then ask, but the RHS has $n+1$ terms. The answer is the last term is $1$, so one may combine last two terms and compare to $n^n$.

<del>Also note that the first two terms are exactly $n^n$. That explains why we needs $n\ge3$.</del>

Comment: +1 for this, because it is more direct than my answer. (But still a little careless: the first two terms are _not_ less than $n^n$.)

Comment: @TonyK I think I covered that  with the last two sentences. But you are right, I could have been more careful with the previous statements.

Comment: Hmmm...that last sentence doesn't look quite right either: if $n=2$, then $n^{n+1}$ is strictly less than $(n+1)^n$. The reason you need $n \ge 3$ is that this gives you $n^2+1<n^n$, allowing you to merge the last two terms.

Comment: Actually, there are $n+1$ terms on the right, so even if each term is less than $n^n$ you just get that $(n+1)n^n>\dots$. This is close to what you want, but not enough.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: My second to last paragraph essentially says what TonyK said.

Comment: @TonyK: exactly what I was trying to say. If we only have two terms, the argument fails. Maybe it's better to take your advice and just change the first argument.

Answer (score 3):

All you need here is the binomial theorem for positive integer exponents:

$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}x^r$$

Fix $n \ge 3$, and put $x = \frac{1}{n}$:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}n^{-r}$$

Now, $\binom{n}{r} \le n^r$ for all $r=0,\ldots,n$ (easily proven by induction; or just look at the expression $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n}{r}\frac{n-1}{r-1}\cdots\frac{n-r+1}{1}$). So

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \le \sum_{r=0}^n n^rn^{-r} = n+1$$

This is not quite good enough for our purposes, but we can improve the estimate by considering the last two terms separately:

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n &\le \sum_{r=0}^{n-2} n^rn^{-r} + \binom{n}{n-1}n^{-(n-1)}+\binom{n}{n}n^{-n} \\
&= n - 1 + n^{-(n-2)}+n^{-n} \\
&< n - 1 + 2n^{-(n-2)} \\
&< n
\end{align}$$

because $n^{n-2} > 2$ if $n \ge 3$, so $n^{-(n-2)} < \frac12$.

Therefore $n > (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ for all $n \ge 3$. Multiplying both sides by $n^n$ gives $n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n$. Taking the $n(n+1)$-th root gives, for all $n \ge 3$,
$$\sqrt[n]{n} > \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$1+\frac{1}{n}<e^{1/n}$$

So $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e$$

For $n>e$ then:

$$\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n<e<n$$

Multiply both sides by $n^n$ and you get:

$$(n+1)^n<n^{n+1}$$

That's not an induction proof, however.

If you don't know the power series for of $e^{x}$, you might prove directly that:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n <3.$$ Namely:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n =\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^{k}}<\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$$

And you can easily see that for $k\geq 1, \frac{1}{k!}\leq\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ so the sum is less than $3$.

Answer (score -1):

Graphing $y=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ , Y has a maximum value at x = e.

[image]

It's all asymptotic to 1 as x approaches infinity

[image]

Updated with graph to show exact area of interest. When properly scaled, it's clear that Y is dropping like a rock as X increases. The good answers here still don't adhere to Op's request for "powers and square roots alone" and his edit of "No calculus, no functions, not even logs."
The highest rated answer? ln x from the start.

Comment: Graphing only gives you a *hint* that this is true, but it is not mathemtically valid to look at a tiny portion of an infinite graph and conclude anything about it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - understood. Yet if i scaled the graph to show x=105, the fact that the maximum was at e would be lost. With OP not wanting a calculus solution, the graph appeared useful, in my opinion. If only to identify the max value.

Comment: Without calculus, how would you identify the maximum is at $e$?

Comment: The (Desmos generated) graph shows the point of interest, the maximum at x = e

Comment: Apparently, you *don't* understand. Sure, if you graphed the two points in question, and had a certainty of precision that you could prove was correct, *then* you would know how to compare. But that proof of correctness is going to be as hard as the original problem. The graph itself is not enough for mathematics. You could also compute $105^{106}$ and $106^{105}$ exactly, which would at least not require any argument about rounding, and thus would be a considerably shorter proof, but it still would b horrible for understanding what was actually going on.

Comment: @QuangHoang It's not too hard, if you assume that $e^x\ge x+1$ for all $x$. (Hint: Substitute in $x=\frac{x'}e-1$.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw Yes, but that is way more than just pointing at the graph, and even if you know that $x=e$ gives the maximum for $x^{1/x}$, that $x^{1/x}$ is necessarily decreasing after that is tricky without calculus. But the main argument here is that the graph shows us *nothing* that is rigorous. It can be a guide for a proof, but it is not a proof in and of itself.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah, I know. I was just answering Hoang's question.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Now I'm thinking how to show $e^x>1+x$ without calculus (jkd).

Comment: Depends on your definition of $e^x$ and your definition of "calculus." :) @QuangHoang

Comment: @QuangHoang You could take that as the _definition_ of $e$ if you want. (I like to do that.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw You define $e^x$ as $e^x>1+x$? That's gonna be a strange definition. :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews To be precise, I define $e$ to be the unique number such that that's true for all $x$. It's really useful :) Challenge: Just using that definition, and without calc, prove that:$$\ln2-\frac1n<1-\frac12+\frac13-\dotsb\frac1n<\ln2+\frac1n$$(and, using the squeeze theorem, show that the alternating harmonic series sums to $\ln2$).

Comment: It might be "really useful" but it isn't a definition.